# javascript function rewrite itself inside function how does it work behind the scene?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

this is some code i have already tried

```
function myFunc(){

    alert("3");

    myFunc = function (){

        alert("something else");

    }


}
```

i want to understand what happens behind the scene in javascript

when i execute `myFunc` its alert 2 and second when i execute it alerts `"something else"`.
what is happening behind the scene when this `myFunc` is called how does function rewrites itself from within the function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myFunc` is in the global namespace, so you can redefine it, which happens when you assign a new function to it with `myFunc = function() ...`.

Functions are objects, and as such can be assigned new definitions over time. You could even set `myFunc = undefined;` if you wanted to prevent the function from running again.

Comment: when we redefine function inside the same function does its activation  object also remains the same

Comment: I think the activation object is not the same, they are different functions.

Comment: @grap_mao yes so do i

Comment: @Rex One reason to do it is so that a function can examine the running environment (CSS or JS support, for example) when called the first time, and then rewrite itself to automatically call the correct version next time, optimising away the overhead of the environment tests.

Answer (score 1):

You're simply redeclaring the function the second time.

On page load, you declare `myFunc()` which alerts 3.
When you execute `myFunc()`, you declare a new function which alerts "something else";